# Model predicts only wrong label despite only using the other label and has 0 specificity but high sensitivity?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

This might be a bit of a long shot but I'm not sure what else I can do. My issue is that I currently have a model that's supposed to be performing binary classification. After training I noticed that the sensitivity is very high (around 98%) but the specificity is close to 0. This was due to the fact that my model was only predicting 1's.

In order to check if the model's properly training or not, I filtered the data so that I would have data samples with only label 0's. However, the result was the same (only 1 predictions) which leads me to believe that my model is not training properly (if at all).

The code is below:

#### Model

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num, dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = 100
        self.embedding_dim = 300
        self.dropout_p = 0.8
        self.feature_dim = dim
        self.num = num

        self.features_linear = nn.Linear(in_features=self.feature_dim, out_features=self.hidden_dim)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.features_linear.weight)

        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=self.num, embedding_dim=self.embedding_dim)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.embedding.weight)

        self.output_linear = nn.Linear(in_features=(self.hidden_dim + self.embedding_dim), out_features=1)
        nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.output_linear.weight)

    def forward(self, a, b):
        a_out = F.relu(self.features_linear(a))
        b_emb = self.embedding(b)
        b_sum = torch.sum(b_emb, dim=1)

        input_rep = torch.cat((a_out, b_sum), dim=1)
        input_rep = self.dropout(input_rep)
        output = self.output_linear(input_rep)

        return output
```

#### Solver code.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import torch
import torch.optim as optim


model = Model(num=16, dim=189)
criterion = nn.BCELoss(reduction='mean')
optimizer = optim.Adam(params=model.parameters())

with open(file='train_data.pkl', mode='rb') as f:
    train_data = pickle.load(f)

for epoch in range(200):
    epoch_loss = 0.0
    predicted_targets = []
    ground_truth_targets = []

    for batch in train_data:
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4, label = batch

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            input_1 = input_1.to('cuda')
            input_2 = input_2.to('cuda')
            input_3 = input_3.to('cuda')
            input_4 = input_4.to('cuda')
            label = label.to('cuda')

        output = input_2

        for i in range(len(input_3)):
            input_data = torch.cat([input_1, output.view(1, -1), input4[i].view(1, -1)], dim=1)
            output = torch.sigmoid(model(input_data, input_3[i].unsqueeze(dim=0)))

        loss = criterion(output, label.float().view(1, -1))
        epoch_loss += loss.item()

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        output_start = input_2.cpu().item()
        output_end = output.cpu().item()
        label_threshold = output_end / output_start
        prediction = 1 if label_threshold <= 0.1 else 0

        predicted_targets.append(prediction)
        ground_truth_targets.append(label.cpu().item())

    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(ground_truth_targets, predicted_targets).ravel()

    sensitivity = tp / (tp + fn)
    specificity = tn / (tn + fp)

    if epoch % 5 == 0:
        print('Epoch: %d | loss: %.6f | sens: %.4f | spec: %.4f' % (epoch, epoch_loss, sensitivity, specificity)
```

Sorry if the code is a bit long, I tried to keep the minimal essential framework in tact without cluttering too much. The data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WgmZYbzCvKDFG5z8DFGXp-K2TofoRUPx/view?usp=sharing).

If anyone can provide some feedback or any ideas on what might be the problem, that'd be greatly appreciated. I've been trying to find out what's wrong for the past couple of weeks but haven't had any luck. Thanks!

Comment: Try training it with literally one example only. What values do you expect in `output_start` and `output_end`? Do you get those values? After training for some number of epochs do you get closer to the expected values? Also, is your loss decreasing?

Comment: I haven't tried training with only one sample, I'll give that a shot. `output_start` is supposed to be an integer-valued scalar ranging from smallest 4 to largest 31. `output_end` is a value between 0 and 1. Dividing `output_end` by `output_start` returns a value within that range as well, and depending on the threshold we're setting the value to 0 or 1. I'm not sure if the number of epochs are influencing the predictions at all, I'll also have a look. Regarding loss, yes it's decreasing very well, which is confusing me even more.

Comment: @JoshVarty I know a couple of days passed, but I managed to try training the thing with only one sample (label 0) and the model still predicts only 1's. Any hunch on what else I could try? Actually it's really weird because it does perfectly fine on the training data, but suddenly does weird stuff on the test data...

Comment: In your original post you said the model only predicts `1` but your comment says it works on the training data. Does it correctly predict `0` and `1` on the training data?